# PHP reports using Mysql on firefox

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am designing a stand alone software using PHP and MYSQL.

I have generated report with HTML and CSS.

But my problem is that the report is 30-40 pages long that is one page contain one vendor bill and when i am printing this pages the Firefox shrinks the size of report.

When i print only one vendor bill it will prints fine.

Please help me.

Comment: that's because pagination exist and ajax. [look this](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement is fine. If you want to display 30-40 page report. But in implementation 
we have to `measure all things like performance of your site` . When you load all data together that is not an optimum solution to do this.

As one of my friends suggest to you should use `pagination or ajax`. Similarly you can also use `lazy loading` here. OR if possible then break your report section wise and keep all section in left or right menu and
on-click on section you can fetch data through ajax and display..

Answer (score 0):

I would use TCPDF for creating PDF files.
It is just a folder you upload to your site. In the folder there are examples which only need a bit of editing.

It is easy because you make the page using not more than simple HTML and elementary PHP.

Comment: TCPDF from http://www.tcpdf.org/ actualy generate the PDFs that you need. Please provide some code in order to get a solution for your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use [TCPD](http://www.tcpdf.org/) or [DOMPDF](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) to generate Report in PDF format. DOMPDF more easier to deal and flexible. It easily convert pure html code to PDF with Formated Layout.